# Difference of the quiescent current and standby current

Tags: power-electronics

What is the difference of quiescent current and standby current ?I have searched but confusing. The definition of quiescent current is the current in standby mode(no load or light load). I know that quiescent current is not shutdown current but is quiescent current  equal to standby current or not?

Comment: It would help to know which exact component you are talking about. Can you add that to the question? Preferably with a link to datasheet.

Comment: It depends on the context of the device.

Comment: @mkeith I'd post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

- **Quiescent current** is current used when the device is not doing anything useful (for example when the output current of a regulator is 0).
- **Standby** is a **MODE OF OPERATION**. So standby current is the current used when the device is in the "standby" mode of operation.

They are not mutually exclusive. You have to read the fine print in the specific datasheet you are considering to see what is what. I would like the OP to modify the question to include links to specific datasheets where these terms are found. But I decided to try to write a general answer anyway.